# Why isn't the DropDownList filter not working for my GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, filter

I have the following code which has a `DropDownList` for each column in my `GridView`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="TasksUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" class="GridviewTable">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 25%;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTaskName" DataSourceID="dsPopulateTaskName" AutoPostBack="false" DataValueField="Task Name" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateTaskName" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [ATTR2739] 'Task Name' FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT LEFT JOIN HSI.USERGROUP UG on CT.FK2743 = UG.USERGROUPNUM WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 20%;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlService" DataSourceID="dsPopulateService" AutoPostBack="false" DataValueField="Service" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateService" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [ATTR2846] 'Service' FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT LEFT JOIN HSI.USERGROUP UG on CT.FK2743 = UG.USERGROUPNUM WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 15%;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" DataSourceID="dsPopulateStatus" AutoPostBack="false" DataValueField="Status" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateStatus" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [ATTR2812] 'Status' FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT LEFT JOIN HSI.USERGROUP UG on CT.FK2743 = UG.USERGROUPNUM WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 15%;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDueDate" DataSourceID="dsPopulateDueDate" AutoPostBack="false" DataValueField="Due Date" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateDueDate" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(14), [ATTR2752], 110) 'Due Date' FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT LEFT JOIN HSI.USERGROUP UG on CT.FK2743 = UG.USERGROUPNUM WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 15%;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClient" DataSourceID="dsPopulateClient" AutoPostBack="false" DataValueField="Client" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateClient" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [ATTR2799] 'Client' FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT LEFT JOIN HSI.USERGROUP UG on CT.FK2743 = UG.USERGROUPNUM WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:GridView ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EBE9E9" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSorting="yourTasksGV_Sorting" AllowSorting="true" ID="yourTasksGV" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" EmptyDataText="There is no data to display" OnRowDataBound="yourTasksGV_RowDataBound" OnRowCreated="yourTasksGV_RowCreated">
            <Columns>
                <asp:HyperLinkField Target="_blank" DataNavigateUrlFields="Task Detail" DataTextField="Task Name" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="" HeaderText="Task Detail" SortExpression="Task Name" ItemStyle-Width="25%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Service" HeaderText="Service" SortExpression="Service" ItemStyle-Width="20%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Due Date" HeaderText="Due Date" SortExpression="Due Date" ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Client" HeaderText="Client" SortExpression="Client" ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsdetails" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT 'http://dmag.com/' + CAST(CT.OBJECTID AS VARCHAR) + '&classid=1224' 'Task Detail', CT.ATTR2846 'Service', CT.ATTR2812 'Status', CT.ATTR2752 'Due Date', CT.ATTR2739 'Task Name', CT.ATTR2799 'Client' FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT LEFT JOIN HSI.USERGROUP UG on CT.FK2743 = UG.USERGROUPNUM WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0" FilterExpression=" [Task Name] Like '{4}%' and [Service] Like '{1}%' and [Status] Like '{2}%' and [Due Date] Like '{3}%' and [Client] Like '{5}%'">
        <FilterParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="Task Name" ControlID="ddlTaskName" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="Service" ControlID="ddlService" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="Status" ControlID="ddlStatus" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="Due Date" ControlID="ddlDueDate" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="Client" ControlID="ddlClient" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </FilterParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The `DropDownList` is displaying the correct values for each column but when I select an option, the `GridView` is not filtering.

I am using `UpdatePanel` so the page doesn't do a Postback when sorting and hence the `DropDownList` `AutoPostBack` is set to false.

**UPDATE**: I am missing the `DataSourceID` from the `GridView` but it is because I am populating and sorting it from code-behind.

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: _"I am using UpdatePanel so the page doesn't do a Postback when sorting and hence the DropDownList AutoPostBack is set to false"_ I think you have misunderstood how ASP.NET ajax works. It _does_ postback but it does only "repaint" the part of the `UpdatePanel`. The page posts back and runs through a full lifecycle anyway. So change it to `AutoPostBack = "true"`.

Comment: Yes, I just realized I said that all wrong. Thank you for correcting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with the updatepanel , it is not going to filter the data on the client side. It has to go server side to filter the data. You have to make

```
                AutoPostBack = true
```

and handle the

```
                SelectedIndex_Change event
```

and then you have call the

```
               updatepanel.update()
```

To handle the Change event, you have to apply the filter on the grid data source and bind the grid again.

Comment: How do I handle the `change` event?

Comment: I took care of it. Thank you :)